# Reading a named pipe continuosly

Tags: python, named-pipes, fifo

What is the best way to read a named pipe continuously in Python?

This is my current code:

```
def read_commands():
    try:
        print "Creating read pipe..."
        os.mkfifo(pipe_cmd)    # Create pipe
        print "Pipe created!"
    except:
        print "Pipe already exists"

    with open(pipe_cmd, "r") as pipecmd:
        while True:
            try:
                line = pipecmd.readline()
            except:
                print "Could not read cmd pipe"

            if line != "":
                print line

        #time.sleep(1)
```

However, when I run this code it seems to be taking a lot of resources from my CPU (One of them will go to 100%). It works fine with the sleep of 1 second. However, I need to read the pipe continuously to make sure if there is **new data**. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

This is what I am sending to the pipe in C++:

```
void write_pipe(){
    ofstream pipe("/tmp/okccmd");  // Open the pipe
    string data = "Hi";
    pipe << data << endl;
    pipe.flush();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: look into the `select` module

Comment: Do you know of any good tutorial I should look into?

Comment: Is there always data to read from the other end of the pipe? The `readline` call should block if there's nothing to read, so I'm surprised you're seeing a CPU spike unless it's actually continuously reading.

Comment: That's what I thought too... No there shouldn't be data always. Unless my C++ program is treating it as a regular file. How should I now if this is the case? I have posted the c++ code.

Comment: @dano I just confirmed it... The readline is not blocking anything! The while loop still continues. Any idea of why this could be the case?

Answer (score 3):

select.poll works fine (at least for Linux, not sure if Windows supports this; select.select ist afaik available, however). Just have a look at the documentation, the module is in the standard library and well documented (there is no need to know how the OS select() function actually works).

Documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html

Note: poll() returns a list of file descriptors, not file-objects. So, you should have a dict which maps file descriptors to the corresponding object (I would have this also if I just poll one file.

```
pollobj = select.poll()
polled_files = dict()

# the following two lines are reuired for every file
pollobj.register(my_file_obj, <EVENTMASK>)
polled_files[my_file_obj.fileno()] = my_file_obj

for fd, evt in pollobj.poll():
    fileobj = polled_files[fd]
    ... process event for fileobj
```

Comment: How would this work in an interleaved fashion? I'd like to poll, but on an extra condition.

Comment: What do you mean with "interleaved" in this context? And what condition? There are no conditions beyond what you can find in the documenation of `poll()`. If you have another question, please open a new one, comments are not for extended discussion of follow-up questions (see [tour] ff). Just do reasonable research **before** asking, see [ask], it's most likely your question has already been asked, mayybe under a different premise (using the standard terms also enhances the chance to find it yourself).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `read` or `readline` functions, you can use `for..in`. This will behave in a blocking manner. If the client side writing to the fifo closes, the for loop ends. The while loop will reopen the fifo and wait.

```
import os

FIFO = 'myfifo'
os.mkfifo(FIFO)
while True:
    with open(FIFO) as fifo:
        for line in fifo:
            print(line)
```